# IMDB api axios get movies by title

Tags: api, axios, imdb

I was doing an exercise last week where I was getting json results rom the imdb api by searching for a title, such as adding 'batman' to the url would return movies with batman in the title, page 1 of # with pagination.

The url was something like: `https://www.imdb.api/search=batman&page=2`

I was using axios.get(url) to get the results, no api key needed, but I seem to have lost the api url I was using in my get request, and have been searching online for how to use the imdb api in this way again but wasnt able to find a working example.

So my question is, what is the api title search url for imdb such that I can make a get request (or put it in my browser) and see the json text results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, as far as I know, and remember, you do need an *API_KEY* to use the *IMDB API*.
The *IMDB API* documentation can be found [here](https://imdb-api.com/api#Title-header).

You can also use The Movie DB (TMDB) API. The API documentation you can find [here](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction). For TMDB you will also need an *API_KEY*.